# Keyboad and mouse pad are not working in Ubuntu-22.04 LTS linux for Lenovo V15 Gen4, 7520U

Tags: keyboard, touchpad, hid

The keyboard and Mouse/touchpad are not working in Ubuntu-22.04 LTS OS on Lenovo V14 Gen4 7520U CPU. The external keyboard and mouse work perfectly. Is there any solution?

Comment: https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/707571